# Collect members from custom tree nodes

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, iteration

In my program, I have a tree of `Group` nodes, each identified by their `ImportId`.

Each group has zero or more members, that I want to collect.

Each group has zero or more child groups, referenced by their importId, whose members should be added to the collection.

Each group has zero or more `RulePart`s.

Each rulePart is a collection of zero or more groups, referenced by their importId, whose members should be added or removed to the collection, depending on a boolean value `Negated` on each rulePart.

I got the following code working:

```
internal class RulePartTraverser
{
    public List<string> GetRulePartMembers(IReadOnlyList<RulePart> ruleParts, IReadOnlyList<Group> allGroups)
    {
        if (ruleParts is null || !ruleParts.Any() || allGroups is null || !allGroups.Any())
        {
            return new List<string>();
        }

        var positiveRuleParts = collectRulePartMembers(ruleParts.Where(rp => !rp.Negated), allGroups);
        var negativeRuleParts = collectRulePartMembers(ruleParts.Where(rp => rp.Negated), allGroups);

        return positiveRuleParts.Except(negativeRuleParts).ToList();
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> collectRulePartMembers(IEnumerable<RulePart> ruleParts, IReadOnlyList<Group> allGroups)
    {
        var members = ruleParts.Aggregate(
            seed: new List<string>().AsEnumerable(),
            (current, rp) => current.Union(collectIndirectMembers(rp.RulePartMemberImportIds, allGroups)));

        return members;
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> collectIndirectMembers(List<string> indirectGroupImportIds, IReadOnlyList<Group> allGroups)
    {
        var returnList = indirectGroupImportIds.Aggregate(
            seed: new List<string>().AsEnumerable(),
            (current, importId) =>
            {
                var correspondingGroup = allGroups.Single(ag => ag.ImportId == importId);
                return current.Union(GetRulePartMembers(correspondingGroup.RuleParts, allGroups))
                .Union(collectIndirectMembers(correspondingGroup.Children, allGroups))
                .Union(correspondingGroup.Members);
            });

        return returnList;
    }
}

public class RulePart
{
    public bool Negated { get; set; }
    public List<string> RulePartMemberImportIds { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string ImportId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Children { get; set; }
    public List<string> Members { get; set; }
    public List<RulePart> RuleParts { get; set; }
}
```

The above method accepts a list of ruleParts for a given group and a list of all groups.

Some sanity checks are performed and if they fail, an empty list is returned.

It then collects all members of all ruleParts that *are not* negated, then collects all members of all ruleParts that *are* negated and substracts the latter from the former. The resulting collection is returned.

In order to collect all members of a single rulePart, all rulePartMembers are inspected and all the members of the corresponding groups are collected.

To collect all members of a given single group, I recursively collect all members of the corresponding ruleParts; then I recursively add the members of all child groups, potentially collecting the members of this child group's ruleParts and this child group's children. Finally I add all direct members of the group and step up.

Due to the nature of my data structure, I fear that this is the best I can do. However, is it possible (or sensible) to replace the recursion by an iteration? Are there other things I could or should improve?

---

The following example is not too far away from a real case scenario, I hope it helps in explaining the data structure:

```
    var rootGroup = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "Root",
        Members = new List<string>(),
        Children = new List<string>(),
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>
        {
            new RulePart{Negated = false, RulePartMemberImportIds = new List<string>{ "group01", "group02" } }, //add all members of groups group01 and group02 to the collection
            new RulePart{Negated = true, RulePartMemberImportIds = new List<string>{"group03", "group04"}} //but remove all members of groups group03 and group04
        }
    };

    var group01 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group01",
        Members = new List<string>(),
        Children = new List<string>(),
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>
        {
            new RulePart{Negated = false, RulePartMemberImportIds = new List<string>{"group05"}}, //add all members of group05
            new RulePart{Negated = true, RulePartMemberImportIds = new List<string>{"group06"}} //remove all members of group06
        }
    };

    var group02 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group02",
        Members = new List<string> { "member01", "member04", "member05" },
        Children = new List<string>(),
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>()
    };

    var group03 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group03",
        Members = new List<string> { "member06", "member07", "member09" },
        Children = new List<string>(),
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>()
    };

    var group04 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group04",
        Members = new List<string> { "member09", "member10", "member11" },
        Children = new List<string>(),
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>()
    };

    var group05 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group05",
        Members = new List<string>(),
        Children = new List<string> { "group07", "group08" }, //add all members of groups group07 and group08
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>()
    };

    var group06 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group06",
        Members = new List<string> { "member02" },
        Children = new List<string>(),
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>()
    };

    var group07 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group07",
        Members = new List<string> { "member12" },
        Children = new List<string>(),
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>()
    };

    var group08 = new Group
    {
        ImportId = "group08",
        Members = new List<string>(),
        Children = new List<string> { "group04" }, //add all members of group04
        RuleParts = new List<RulePart>()
    };

    var expectedMembers = new List<string> { "member01", "member04", "member05", "member12" };
```

The rule parts of the `Root`Group would serve as input to `GetRulePartMembers`.

In order to collect the members of the different rule parts, first the members of groups `group01` - `group04` have to be determined.

For `group01`, this means determining the members of the ruleparts of `group01`, ie determining the members of groups `group05` and `group06`, as these are ruleparts of `group01`.

As `group05` has child groups, the members of `group05` is the union of the members of groups `group07` and `group08`, `group08` has a single child group `group04`, so the members of `group08` are the members of `group04`, yielding `member09, member10, member11` for `group08`, resulting in `member09, member10, member11, member12` for `group05`.

The single member of `group06` is `member02`, removing it from the result collection of `group05` results in the collection `member09, member10, member11, member12` for `group01`.

For `group02`, the members are directly `member01, member04, member05`, which results in the member collection `member01, member04, member05, member09, member10, member11, member12` for the non-negated rulepart of the `Root`Group.

For the negated rulepart of the `Root`Group, the members of `group03` and `group04` can directly be added to the result collection, as neither of the groups have children or ruleparts. This results in `member06, member07, member09, member10, member11` for the negated rulepart.

These members are then removed from the collection of members for the non-negated rulepart, yielding the final result of `member01, member04, member05, member12` for the `Root`Group.

Answer (score 4):

Just a couple of tipps...

---

> ```
> if (ruleParts is null || !ruleParts.Any() || allGroups is null || !allGroups.Any())
> ```

This sanity checks would be a big surprise for me because `null` is virtually never a valid value so this method should throw if any parameter is `null`.

Having checked for `null`s it's not necessary to also check them for `Any`. The queries wouldn't return anything anyway in this case so just let them do the job.

---

> ```
>   var positiveRuleParts = collectRulePartMembers(ruleParts.Where(rp => !rp.Negated), allGroups);
>   var negativeRuleParts = collectRulePartMembers(ruleParts.Where(rp => rp.Negated), allGroups);
> ```

You don't have to iterate `ruleParts` twice. Instead use `ToLookup`

```
var rulePartsLookup = ruleParts.ToLookup(x => x.Negated);
```

and get the values with

```
collectRulePartMembers(rulePartsLookup[false], allGroups);
collectRulePartMembers(rulePartsLookup[true], allGroups);
```

---

> ```
> new List<string>().AsEnumerable()
> ```

It's more *natural* to use `Enumerable.Empty<string>()` than creating an empty list and turn it into an enumerable anyway.

---

I cannot comment on the recursion because I am not able to visualize it without an example.

Comment: Thanks, I have incorporated your tips. What is the practice on CodeReview regarding code changes in the original question? I have also added an example of some groups and ruleparts and the expected outcome of the recursion, along with an explanation how to determine the result.

Comment: @Thaoden You did the right thing by not chaniging the original code ;-) it's not allowed after reviews have been posted. Adding an additional example is a great help too. If you want to share your new code you can post a self-answer or a follow-up if you'd like to have more feedback. There is, however, a catch when posting a self-answer - this needs to be described too - code-only answers are off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

If a `Member` can be owned by more groups that can correspond to `RulePart`s that can be either `Negated` or not, and that the `Negated` ownership take precedence over `!Negated`, I understand your code:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRulePartMembers2(IEnumerable<RulePart> ruleParts, IEnumerable<Group> allGroups)
{
  IEnumerable<string> ExtractMembers(IEnumerable<RulePart> partialRuleParts, bool negated)
  {
    return partialRuleParts
      .Where(rp => rp.Negated == negated)
      .SelectMany(rp => rp.RulePartMemberImportIds)
      .SelectMany(importId =>
      {
        Group group = allGroups.Single(g => g.ImportId == importId);
        var children = allGroups.Where(g => group.Children.Contains(g.ImportId));
        return group
        .Members
        .Union(ExtractMembers(group.RuleParts, negated)
              .Union(ExtractMembers(children.SelectMany(sg => sg.RuleParts), negated)))
        .Union(children.SelectMany(sg => sg.Members));
      });
  }

  return ExtractMembers(ruleParts, false).Except(ExtractMembers(ruleParts, true));       

}
```

If I test against your solution in the following way, I get the same result. I assume that the initial list of `RulePart`s is the gross list of all:

```
  var groups = new[]
  {
    rootGroup,
    group01,
    group02,
    group03,
    group04,
    group05,
    group06,
    group07,
    group08,
  };

  var ruleParts = rootGroup.RuleParts; //groups.SelectMany(g => g.RuleParts).ToList();

  var expectedMembers = new List<string> { "member01", "member04", "member05", "member12" };

  RulePartTraverser traverser = new RulePartTraverser();

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", traverser.GetRulePartMembers(ruleParts, groups).OrderBy(m => m)));
  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", traverser.GetRulePartMembers2(ruleParts, groups).OrderBy(m => m)));
```

I'm not convinced that my solution is more readable and clear than the yours - any more.

---

**Update:**

In order to only iterate the rule parts once for both `Negated` and `!Negated` the following could be a solution:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetRulePartMembers2(Group rootGroup, IEnumerable<Group> allGroups)
{
  List<string> positiveMembers = new List<string>();
  List<string> negativeMembers = new List<string>();

  void AddMembers(RulePart rulePart, Group group)
  {
    if (rulePart.Negated)
      negativeMembers.AddRange(group.Members);
    else
      positiveMembers.AddRange(group.Members);
  }

  void ExtractMembers(IEnumerable<RulePart> partialRuleParts)
  {
    foreach (RulePart rulePart in partialRuleParts)
    {
      foreach (Group group in allGroups.Where(g => rulePart.RulePartMemberImportIds.Contains(g.ImportId)))
      {
        AddMembers(rulePart, group);
        ExtractMembers(group.RuleParts);

        foreach (Group childGroup in allGroups.Where(cg => group.Children.Contains(cg.ImportId)))
        {
          // This is the only thing that is not obvious: 
          // The members of a child group are added according to the rulePart of its parent?
          AddMembers(rulePart, childGroup);
          ExtractMembers(childGroup.RuleParts);
        }

      }
    }
  }

  ExtractMembers(rootGroup.RuleParts);

  return positiveMembers.Except(negativeMembers);
}
```

Comment: Exactly, a `member` can be part of multiple `group`s, that can in turn each be part of multiple `rulepart`s, that in turn can be negated or not. Additionally, each `group` can be part of another `group`s `children`. I'm not sure I understand what is happening in your `ExtractMembers` method though, how would I incorporate the childgroups there?

Comment: @Thaoden: see my update...

Comment: Not exactly, the initial list of ruleParts to start is only the `rulePart`s of the `Root`Group - at least that was my initial intention. So basically you go through the list of all ruleparts twice, collecting _all_ non-negated and _all_ negated members and removing the negated from the non-negated - I'm not sure this would yield the same result for all cases, I would have to think of a counter-example though...

Comment: @Thaoden: OK, it seems to work with just `rootGroup.RuleParts` as initial list of `RuleParts`, and you can optimize it, as my edit show. But don't waste time on my suggestion, I was just trying to understand your problem and it doesn't seem to make anything clearer :-)

Comment: @Thaoden: I was challenged by your question and have made an update of my answer.

Comment: The members of a child group are added unconditionally. Thanks for your input, I especially like the fact that these are local functions, so I don't have to pass all the references around.